# How can I use Node.js with the filesystem to map a fake drive?

Tags: node.js, filesystems

When mapping a network drive in windows or mounting an SSH drive in Linux, it appears to the OS as a regular drive even though it's a completely different protocol and filesystem behind the scenes.

There are programs that can do that for you like CloudMounter and MountainDuck so I'm wondering:

Is there a cross-platform way I can use Node.js to do something similar?

Comment: *When mapping a network drive in windows or mounting an SSH drive in Linux* - so what OS are you asking about? Node isn't supposed to do anything like that out of the box. It may be possible with third-party packages or CLI tools, depending on what exactly is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node.js doesn't have a built-in way to do this but the popular FUSE library (https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse) has bindings on NPM:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/fuse-bindings
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/fused

(I wrote the second one)

Comment: Thanks! I updated my question. I was also hoping for something where I didn't have to install a 3rd party utility and could just use Node.js. Looks like that's not possible especially if I want something cross-platform. Looks like I might have to include some FUSE libraries with my app then.